# Setter for class is not being called

Tags: ios, objective-c, class, selector, setter

I am trying to implement a car2go style app where you click on an annotation view and then can reserve the car. The problem is when I try to segue I want to pass the car object over, I check if the object performs the selector set vehicle but the if statement fails although I am pretty sure it is implemented. Can someone tell me why? This is for a school project.

```
#import "MapViewController.h"
#import <MapKit/MapKit.h>
#import <CoreLocation/CoreLocation.h>
#import "Vehicles+Company.h"  
#import "Vehicles+MKAnnotation.h"

-(void) prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender{

if ([segue.identifier isEqualToString:@"reserveCar"]) {
    if ([sender isKindOfClass:[MKAnnotationView class]]) {
        MKAnnotationView *aView = sender;
        if ([aView.annotation isKindOfClass:[Vehicles class]]) {
            Vehicles *vehicle = aView.annotation;
            if ([segue.destinationViewController respondsToSelector:@selector(setVehicle:)]) {
                [segue.destinationViewController performSelector:@selector(setVehicle:) withObject:vehicle];
            }
        }
    }
}

}
```

This is the viewcontroller it is segueing to.

.h file

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
#import "Vehicles+MKAnnotation.h"
#import "Vehicles.h"
#import "Vehicles+Company.h"


@interface CompanyVehicleViewController : UIViewController

@property (nonatomic,strong) Vehicles *vehicle;

@end
```

.m file

```
#import "CompanyVehicleViewController.h"

@interface CompanyVehicleViewController ()

@end

@implementation CompanyVehicleViewController

-(void) setVehicle:(Vehicles *)vehicle{
_vehicle = vehicle;
self.title = vehicle.name;
NSLog(@"Vehicle is %@", vehicle);
}

- (id)initWithNibName:(NSString *)nibNameOrNil bundle:(NSBundle *)nibBundleOrNil
{
self = [super initWithNibName:nibNameOrNil bundle:nibBundleOrNil];
if (self) {
    // Custom initialization
}
return self;
 }

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
[super viewDidLoad];
// Do any additional setup after loading the view.
 }

@end
```

Comment: Confirm that `segue.destinationViewController` is really an instance of `CompanyVehicleViewController`.

Comment: Use the debugger or add an `NSLog` statement.

Comment: it says its a class of UIViewController not CompanyVehicleViewController, how do I fix this?

Comment: There should be a way to change the class of the view controller in the segue.

Comment: I see I didn't set the viewcontroller to be that class in the story board, thanks! Want to make an answer so I can give you the points

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Most likely `segue.destinationViewController` isn't an instance of `CompanyVehicleViewController`.

Verify in your storyboard that the view controller's type is set to the proper class.